# C++ Command Line Apps on Android?

Tags: c++, android, shell, command-line

Is it possible to make a command line app for linux, and then run it on android with shell? Since android runs on linux, I don't see why there would be any problems running it. I know that /system/bin/* has all the things you can use from adb so this should be the same.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is with the Android build system, since it has all the necessary cross-compile libs set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here is one claim of [doing this successfully](http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/13/android-native-apps).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you're correct.

Better try that out!